# How to bind the total items in the data grid to the component while using Clarity Design (VM clarity). Data grid with server pagination

Tags: angular, pagination, angular8, server-side-rendering, vmware-clarity

I am a newbie in VM clarity, I was trying to implement server-side pagination. I need to get the total items in the data grid after filtering. I can display the values in HTML by using pagination object reference. How can I bind the pagination object to the component? 
I am getting the page change and filter changes by using 'onDgRefresh' event.

```
   <clr-datagrid (clrDgRefresh)="onDgRefresh($event)" class="item-datagrid"
*ngIf="showCondition" [clrDgLoading]="gridRefreshing">
```

Here is my clr-dg-footer.

```
    <clr-dg-footer>
  <clr-dg-pagination  #pagination [clrDgPageSize]="10">
    <clr-dg-page-size [clrPageSizeOptions]="[10,20,50,100]">per page</clr-dg-page-size>
    {{pagination.totalItems}} items
  </clr-dg-pagination>
</clr-dg-footer>
```

I have to invoke the API whenever the count of items in the grid less than a certain size. So I have to
get the count of items in the grid. Is there any option to get the total Items? I tried

```
   <clr-dg-pagination [clrDgTotalItems]="totalItemsInGrid" #pagination [clrDgPageSize]="10">
```

but didn't work.

VM clarity version 2.0
angular version: 8

Comment: Filtering is server driven data grids is handled on the server. the server driven data grid will display all of the filtered items returned. I’ll have to double check the code but I believe that the total items is the total filtered items returned to the datagrid so that if the filtered items is greater the datagrid knows how many items per page and how many pages there will be for the filtered items. From what I understand, this should be handled on the server when the datagrid refresh method is called with the updated filter.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use "pagination.totalItems" you need to add the [clrDgTotalItems] property. The value of this property will be referred as  "totalItems" in component property.

Here is the updated markup of yours.

```
<clr-dg-pagination  #pagination [clrDgPageSize]="10" [clrDgTotalItems]="<your total count>">
    <clr-dg-page-size [clrPageSizeOptions]="[10,20,50,100]">per page</clr-dg-page-size>
        {{pagination.totalItems}} items
</clr-dg-pagination>
```

This will show you the total items correctly.

Here is my implementation

```
<clr-dg-pagination #pagination [clrDgTotalItems]="users.length">
     <clr-dg-page-size [clrPageSizeOptions]="[10,20,50,100]">Users per page</clr-dg-page-size>
       {{pagination.firstItem + 1}} - {{pagination.lastItem + 1}} of {{pagination.totalItems}} users
 </clr-dg-pagination>
```

Reference : https://v2.clarity.design/datagrid/pagination

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work in server-side pagination by having our API return the total number of results along with the paged result data.

The total items can be set in your footer by just changing {{pagination.totalItems}} to {{someOtherValue}}, which is the value you get back from the server. In other words, don't rely on the plugin's totalItems value since it won't have the total count from the server. Substitute in your own value here.